# Data transfer between two applications using libUSB (host and target model)

Tags: data-transfer, libusb-1.0

I am trying to find a way to send and receive data over a USB connection connected using a cable. The idea is: A service/command line application will be running on target system, receives commands, and send data for the command. A GUI application sitting on the other machine analyses and interprets the data.

Using libUSB, is it possible?

Comment: What are your target systems?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to connect to PC's together it will not be possible.
The USB protocol is a Master-Slave protocol. Most USB adapters only support either the Master mode or Slave mode. So you will not be able to connect two PC's with USB.

You would have to have special hardware on one of the PC's to act as USB slave.